# fourth powers as sums of squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is it possible to have a fourth power that is the sum of two squares in four different ways, e.g., $w^4 = a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2 = e^2 + f^2 = g^2 + h^2$ with the added restriction that $e = a+c$ and $g = a-c$ ?  What is the lowest example, or why is it impossible?

Comment: What's the motivation for chaining together these restrictions that seem quite arbitrary?

Comment: Hi Erick, this restriction is key to the solution (or otherwise) of a famous unsolved problem relating to 3 by 3 magic squares.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you'll find that people are more willing to think about problems if they are given some context.  You might consider including this in the description of the question, as well as mentioning what avenues you've already pursued (even just computation).

Comment: Also, the question seems incomplete as stated.  It admits the trivial family of solutions $a = d = e = g = w^2$, $b = c = f = h = 0$ (technically not all "different" but other similar tricks might work).  Maybe you wanted all variables to be nonzero?  This is another reason why it's important to give enough context, so that we don't have to read your mind to guess at missing details.

Comment: Hi Erick, thanks for your comments.  To be clear, all numbers need to be distinct positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Since $e=a+c$ and $g=a-c$, then the OP wishes to solve the system,

$$a^2 + b^2= c^2 + d^2\tag1$$ 
$$a^2 + b^2= (a+c)^2 + f^2\tag2$$
$$a^2 + b^2= (a-c)^2 + h^2\tag3$$ 
$$a^2 + b^2= w^4\tag4$$

It turns out that, using an *elliptic curve*, there is an infinite number of primitive integer solutions to the first $3$ conditions. However, it is highly doubtful the $4$th can be satisfied as well.

The first was *completely* solved by Brahmagupta as,

$$a,\;b,\;c,\;d = p r + q s,\; p s - q r,\; p r - q s,\; p s + q r$$

The second and third become,

$$-(3 p^2 - q^2) r^2 + (p^2 + q^2) s^2 = f^2$$
$$(p^2 + q^2) r^2 + (p^2 - 3q^2) s^2 = h^2$$

For example, let $p=1,\;q=2$, then,

$$r^2+5s^2=f^2\tag5$$
$$5r^2-11s^2=h^2\tag6$$

with initial rational point $r=178,\; s=19$. Two quadratic polynomials to be made a square and that has a rational point can be transformed into an elliptic curve, so $(5),(6)$ has infinitely many primitive solutions.

Thus, one small solution to the first three conditions is then,

$$a,\;b,\;c,\;d = 216,\; 337,\; 140,\; 375$$
$$f,\;h =183, \;393 $$

The problem is the fourth condition which becomes,

$$a^2+b^2=(p^2+q^2)(r^2+s^2) = w^4\tag7$$

A *third* quadratic that is to be made not just a square but a *fourth* power, makes it highly unlikely that $(5),(6),(7)$ can be solved simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

Select a pythogorean triplet of your choice.square root the answer.multyply each x and y with the answer.say x is 3 , y is 4 .the square root is 5.then (3×5)squared plus(4×5)squared equals 5^4.two squares equal to a fourth power

Comment: I can't quite follow this reasoning. Can you give an example with some Pythagorean triplet (perhaps (3,4,5)) to clarify the procedure?

Comment: I do not have a rigorous proof