# For two odd primes $p<q$, can we deduce positive integers $a,b$ solving $a^2+b^4=pq$ without trial & error (brute force)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Let us fix two primes $p,q$ with $2<p<q$. How can we find positive integers $a,b$ which solve the equation $a^2+b^4=pq$ without brute force?

Interestingly there exist sometimes two solutions:

- $5\cdot13=7^2+2^4=8^2+1^4$
- $5\cdot821=3^2+8^4=53^2+6^4$
- $17\cdot113=25^2+6^4=36^2+5^4$

In more rare cases I even obtain three solutions, e.g.:

- $73\cdot89=49^2+8^4=64^2+7^4=79^2+4^4$

Is there a systematic way to obtain the solutions $a,b$ directly? Or at least, can we establish a relationship between the two primes and these natural solutions? I generated a [CSV file](http://sultanow.info/public/grouped.csv) containing some more cases, which maybe help in finding patterns or connections between $p,q$ and $a,b$.

Can we anticipate (state in advance) how many positive integer solutions we will get depending on $p,q$?

Comment: Well, one algorithmic approach is to solve $a^2+c^2=pq$, which is a more standard problem, and then see if either $a, c$ are themselves squares.

Comment: Sorry I really forget to ask that I would like to deduce the solutions without brute forcing $a,b$ if possible. Are there algebraic structures I may use to find such solutions in a mathematical way?

Comment: Not sure what you consider brute force.  The standard methods for solving $a^2+b^2=N$ involve some case work.  Since your equation solves that problem as well, I don't think you can avoid it.

Comment: My hope was (and still a little bit is) that it is possible to find some constraints on $a$ and $b$ (based on $p,q$) which enables us to find solutions directly. If there are no such structures, of course iterating $a,b$ and searching a soution by brute force is the only way.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: Well, there's a lot of thought that goes into solving the classical problem.  [here](http://ericmoorhouse.org/handouts/two_squares.pdf) for instance, and you can find plenty of other discussions online.  My instincts would be to just run those algorithms and check for squares amongst the solutions, though possibly one could just adapt the methods to your system.  I doubt that would save any time though...it's pretty easy to tell if a number is a square.

Comment: @user2661923: The source of the problem goes a little bit into the direction of elliptic curves and I am inspired by this interesting post too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567892/fourth-powers-as-sums-of-squares

Comment: @lulu: Thank you very much for the paper link: http://ericmoorhouse.org/handouts/two_squares.pdf. It is really a good start into this topic.

Comment: What is the source of this question? An eerily similar question was asked [earlier today](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4051990/11619).

Comment: The source is an elliptic curve related problem (which might give some insights into cryptography). It is a bit related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567892/fourth-powers-as-sums-of-squares Concretely we are studying elliptic curves of the form $y^2=x^3-pqx$ where $p<q$ are odd primes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\quad a^2+b^4=pq\quad$
we can use a formula for generating Pythagorean triples where $C-A=2\qquad$ Here, $\quad A=4n^2-1\quad B=4n\quad C=4n^2+1.\qquad$ If we let $\quad b^4=4n\quad$ we find integer $n-values$ when $B\in\big\{2,4,6,8,\cdots\big\}$ These correspond to the triples

$$(63,16,65)\qquad (16383,256,16385)\qquad (419903,1296,419905)\\ (4194303,4096,4194305)\qquad (24999999,10000,25000001)\qquad  \cdots$$

In these cases, we can see the $C$=values are composite and easily represented as $pq$, but whether or not $pq$ are prime must be determined for each case.

We can find more "candidates" but still have to check $pq$ for primality by using Euclid's formulas shown here as $ \qquad A=m^2-k^2\qquad B=2mk \qquad C=m^2+k^2.\qquad$ If we solve the $B$-function for $k$, we need only test a defined range of $m$=values to see which yield integers for $k$.

\begin{equation}
B=2mk\implies k=\frac{B}{2m}\qquad\text{for}\qquad \bigg\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{2B+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor \le m \le \frac{B}{2}
\end{equation}
The lower limit ensures $m>k$ and the upper limit ensures $m\ge 2$
$$B=16\implies\qquad \bigg\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{32+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor =3 \le m \le \frac{16}{2}=8\\ \land \quad m\in\{8\}\implies k\in\{1\}$$
$$F(8,1)=(63,16,65)\qquad $$

This generates many non-primitives and a few more primitives where each $C$-value must be screened as above. Those primitives corresponding to the above $B$-values are.

$$f(8,1)=(63,16,65)\qquad  f(128,1)=(16383,256,16385)\\ f(81,8)=(6497,1296,6625)\qquad f(648,1)=(419903,1296,419905)\\ f(2048,1)=(4194303,4096,4194305)\quad f(625,8)=(390561,10000,390689)\\
 f(5000,1)=(24999999,10000,25000001)\qquad $$

Answer (score 0):

With kind assistance I have received a useful hint for a direction to investigate, wich I would like to share with you all:

In the case that $p\equiv3\pmod4$ or $q\equiv3\pmod4$ no solution exist.

Let us set $p=r^2+s^2$ and $q=u^2+v^2$. If $p\equiv1\pmod4$ and $q\equiv1\pmod4$ we exactly obtain one solution $r>s>0$ for $p$ and one solution $u>v>0$ for $q$.

If we now have these unique solutions $p=r^2+s^2$ and $q=u^2+v^2$, then the product of both primes is $pq=(r^2+s^2)(u^2+v^2)=(ru+sv)^2+(rv-su)^2=(ru-sv)^2+(rv+su)^2$.

Consider $b^2=c$, other integer solutions for $pq=a^2+c^2=a^2+b^4$ do not exist, unless one of the four integers $ru+sv$, $|rv-su|$, $|ru-sv|$ and $rv+su$ is a perfect square.

To retrace what happens in practice, I generated variuos cases, where three solutions exist (feel free to download the [CSV](http://sultanow.info/public/grouped.csv)):

- $p\cdot q=233\cdot12409=256^2+41^4=1616^2+23^4=1681^2+16^4$
- $p\cdot q=89\cdot233=1^2+12^4=129^2+8^4=144^2+1^4$
- $p\cdot q=17\cdot4241=81^2+16^4=256^2+9^4=264^2+7^4$

In the first case we have $p=233=8^2+13^2$ and $q=12409=72^2+85^2$.

In the second case we have $p=89=5^2+8^2$ and $q=233=8^2+13^2$.

In the third case we have $p=17=1^2+4^2$ and $q=4241=4^2+65^2$.

Hypothetically, there could be four solutions, although so far I have only found these cases with a maximum of three solutions?